# Basename of the root directory: why does it return the root directory itself?

Tags: filenames, command

`basename /` returns `/`, but the manpage says `Print NAME with any leading directory components removed`. Certainly `/` is a leading directory component and has not been removed.

What's the rationale behind this? And is it documented anywhere? My searches haven't found anything.

In contrast, php's basename() function returns the empty string for that case.

Comment: POSIX specification is [there](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html). What would you like it returns instead?

Comment: FWIW, note that `$(dirname /)/$(basename /)` gives `///` which (contrary to `//`) is equivalent to `/`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of looking for the posix spec and my google searches didn't show up anything. If you want to repost that as a response, I will vote that as the solution. About your question: no personal preference, I just wanted an explanation.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think you've lost me here. According to [man path_resolution](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html), it looks like in the case of `//`, the trailing slash should be dropped and the path resolved to `/`. For `///`, I think you'd get into a recursion where the final `/` is dropped, then tried to resolve, and the middle `/` dropped, ending up again with `/`. What did I miss?

Comment: @doneal24 see [On what systems is //foo/bar different from /foo/bar?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/256497). `//foo` is not guaranteed to be the same as `/foo`. Not sure about `//` specifically. Your man page seems to be about Linux where `//` is not treated specially.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, as the OP mentions, in php, `basename("/")` returns the empty string. So does csh, vim and bash's equivalent `:t` modifier (not zsh's)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I did jump to a Linux answer which is way too specific for this forum. My reading of the links seem to indicate that a Windows-like reading of the path can be used to say that `//foo/bar` is the directory `foo` on host `bar`. Weird but plausible.

Comment: the directory `bar` on host `foo` perhaps?

Comment: FWIW, [the original implementation of basename in v7 in 1979](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/basename.c) would have returned the empty string for both `/` and `/any/dir/` AFAICT.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The code in your link doesn't compile on CentOS 7. Too many arguments to puts on line 27. I'll have to check on an older system.